# Applying operation on groupby row given multiple conditions on row axes

Tags: python, group-by

I have a hundredth thousands line dataframe with players results (score) for two tests (left hand and right hand, cf. Laterality. Some cases are uninformed and are U, hence not testable), that must be performed in some way (hence "Testable" can be either OK or Invalid). In some cases, player can only test one hand (Missing_Lat). Some tests have misattributed lateralities, missing_lat should not be equal to laterality, else test is invalid.
-My task is to take the max score for both lateralities, but there must be at least 2 testable results for each.
-I also have to make calculations on all valid tests for a player, but he must have all possible valid lateralities (hence, if no missing laterality, he must have testable laterality -at least 2 fine tests- for each).

In the end, I have to write a file at both level (hand or player) where I give results for testable hands/players, ignoring invalid results but telling if lateralities or players are untestable if they only have such results.

ie
file 1
player hand result
tommy  L    Untestable
tommy  R    OK
julia  R    OK
julia  L    Unavailable

file 2
player result
tommy  Untestable
julia  OK

Sample data

```
data = [['tom',1], ['tom',2], ['tom',3],
    ['tom',4], ['tom',5], ['tom',6],
     ['julia',7], ['julia',8], ['julia',9],
    ['julia',10], ['julia',11], ['julia',12],['julia',13]]

dfA = ps.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Player ID","Test ID"])
dfA["Lat"] =["L","L","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","L","U"]
dfA["MissingEye"] =["","","","","","","L","L","L","L","L","L","L"]
dfA["Quality"] =[5,-3,np.nan,10,6,-2,5,-3,6,10,6,-2,np.nan]
dfA["testable"]=["OK","OK","INV","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK","INV","INV"]



player_ID   Test_ID Laterality  Score   MissingTest Testable
0   tommy   1   L       5.0 OK
1   tommy   2   L       -3.0    OK
2   tommy   3   R       NaN INV
3   tommy   4   R       10.0    OK
4   tommy   5   R       6.0 OK
5   tommy   6   R       -2.0    OK
6   julia   7   R   L   5.0 OK
7   julia   8   R   L   -3.0    OK
8   julia   9   R   L   6.0 OK
9   julia   10  R   L   10.0    OK
10  julia   11  R   L   6.0 OK
11  julia   12  L   L   -2.0    INV
12  julia   12  U   L   -   INV
```

I can calculate which lateralities are "testable"

```
dfA["Player_Lat_Type_nImgs"]=dfA.groupby(by = ["player_ID","Laterality", "Testable"], axis=0, as_index=False, sort = False)["Image_ID"].transform("count")
dfA["Pt_Lat_Assessable"]=(dfA["Player_Lat_Type_nImgs"]>=2)&(dfA["Laterality"]!="U")
```

But from here I'm stuck.
(What I show is one score but there are actually multiple columns/files, I have to make the max operation for multiple files)

I can actually make

```
        currentLatFrameBase = currentFrame.groupby(by = ["player_ID","Laterality", "Testable"], axis=0, as_index=False, sort = False)
        
             
        currentLatFrame = currentLatFrameBase[f"Score"].max()
        $
        currentLatFrame[f"Decision"] = currentEyeFrame.loc[:,f"Score"]>= threshold #check against threshold
```

But I don't know how to select only valid results, how to take into account that some players have no valid tests or no valid tested sides.

Any suggestions, please? I'm obvious about the fact that my limited knowledge of apply/transform operation limits my reasonning here...